# Bluetooth Programming in C on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I am following this link http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/ , but i am getting error because that sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev is not working ,I am not able to use apt-get command, because i am not connected to internet, but if i download these library from outside and use in my ubuntu PC through pendrive , is it possible 1) Glib library, 2) Dbus library,3) Bluez 4) Bluez Utilities

Comment: So.. this question is asking if its possible to install software on a computer from a USB device?

Comment: [apt-offline](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) might help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Bluez is a Bluetooth Software Stack.
It is composed by three main pieces of software:

- kernel modules
- user level library
- tools and applications

Then, you can decide to use only the kernel modules (and their IOCTL interfaces) and so you have to write by yourself libraries and tools. This is an hard work and the effort depends on which Bluetooth  profile you need to use.

A second way is to download and compile source code: http://www.bluez.org/development/
But you need to install all dependencies on your system.

Regarding APT you can try to get a CD of packages and then use it as source: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-basico.en.html